# How to insert data at initialisation of nodejs express application

Tags: node.js, express, backend, typeorm

I would also like that on multiple runs the data is not stacked multiple times.

I have done this once with spring boot's CommandLineRunner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HamstergotchiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HamstergotchiApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Add challenges on startup if there are no challenges in the database.
     * This will be run at startup.
     */
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initializeDB(ChallengeRepository challengeRepository){
        return (args)->{
            // Add default challenges if the DB is empty
            if(challengeRepository.count() == 0) {
                challengeRepository.save(new Challenge(0, ChallengeType.GEEN_ALCOHOL, false));
                challengeRepository.save(new Challenge(0, ChallengeType.MINDER_FRISDRANK_MET_SUIKER, true));
                challengeRepository.save(new Challenge(0, ChallengeType.GROENTE_EN_FRUIT_20_PROCENT, false));
                challengeRepository.save(new Challenge(0, ChallengeType.GEEN_VLEES, true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want a separate script/command to initialize the database.

If you don't want that, well, just something like

```
async function initializeDatabase() {
  if(databaseContainsEntries()) return;
  addEntry(...);
  addEntry(...);
  addEntry(...);
  addEntry(...);
}

async function boot() {
  await initializeDatabase();
  app.listen(...);
}

boot();
```

instead of a vanilla

```
app.listen(...);
```